# Does ie8 not support the API interface of HTTPS protocol？

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jsonp

Get the data with jquery's jsonp request

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>test demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
        <script src="http://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body >
      </body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
          // url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5', // Ie8 failure
          // url: 'http://suggestion.baidu.com/su?wd=11&p=3&t=1526957301796', Ie8 success
          // url: 'https://api.ipify.org/?format=jsonp', // Ie8 failure
          url: 'http://api.ipify.org/?format=jsonp', // Ie8 succeeded (with the same api as the previous one, but with different protocols)
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          type: 'get',
          // jsonp: "cb", 
          success: function(res){
            console.log(res)
          },
          error: function(err){
            console.log('err', err)
         }
       })
    </script>
  </html>
```

In addition, it is also found that as long as jquery CDN address with HTTPS is introduced, such as

```
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.js"></script>
```

it will be '$' is undefine
Is that ie8 does not support HTTPS jsonp? Because there has been no official statement and no clear answer, I hope there is a definite answer;
thanks very much

Comment: Does it work if you change the script include to be `<script src="http://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.js"></script>` Trying this will eliminate the "http/https" theory. Also, are you using any addition javascript libraries? e.g., mootools, etc..

Comment: No other libraries，just a pure demo；and use ```<script src="http://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.js"></script>``` it work

Comment: Could you post the full code?

Comment: @varlogtim  I modified the problem and post the full demo code

Comment: Based on your x-ua-compatible setting and your <!doctype> declaration, your page is being rendered in IE5 Quirks mode.

If you want this page to render in IE8 Standards mode (so that it supports the features in IE8), you need to set x-ua-compatible to `IE8` and add an HTML5 [<!doctype> declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/cc288325(v%3dvs.85)).  (Even then, you may not see the results you want.


Note: jQuery currently [requires IE9](https://jquery.com/browser-support/)